# Is $||A^\top A + B^\top B||_2 \ge || A^\top A ||_2$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove the following statement, which feels very natural, but I am having very little success.

> For matrices $A,B$, we have $||A^\top A + B^\top B||_2 \ge  || A^\top A ||_2$.

I feel like this should be true, because  $B^\top B$ is positive semidefinite, and on an intuitive level I think adding two positive semidefinite matrices can only add more information to the positive singular values. But I cannot prove this; the difficulty is that the SVD of $A$ and $B$ do not interact well. Is there a proof to this? Or is it even true?

Comment: Hint. For every real symmetric $n \times n$ matrix $M$, $||M||_2 = \sup\{|\langle x,Mx \rangle| / \langle x,x \rangle : x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}\}$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan that's a very useful statement! Could you help me understand why that is true? Edit: I think we might use the orthogonal eigendecompostion via the spectral theorem, and that in this case the singular values of M are the absolute value of eigenvalues of M?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews is this true? Doesn't the triangular inequality imply that $||U+V||_2 = ||U||_2 + ||V||_2 $ in this case? That sounds too strong to be true, even if U and V are positive semidefinite.

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote. You need, to satisfy your intuition, that if $U,V$ are positive semi-definite, that $\|U+V\|_2\geq \|U\|_2.$ Not sure if that is true, but if your intuition is about positive semi-definite-ness, then this is the statement you want to prove.

Comment: @Clarent. Indeed, this follows from the orthogonal eigendecompostion via the spectral theorem. For self-adjoint matrices, the singular values are the modulus of the eigenvalues.